# DomPDF Codeigniter charset not correctly rendered

Tags: php, codeigniter, dompdf, fgetcsv

I have a nifty problem with DomPDF, it does bug-up accented characters.
I did everything that Phil Sturgeon suggests on [Phil Sturgeon on UTF-8 support for Codeigniter](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2009/08/UTF-8-support-for-CodeIgniter) 
But with the only result that the first page of the PDF is okay but the rest is wrong.

Anyone any suggestions or solutions?

B.t.w. I import through a csv-file with PHP fgetcsv(), my php-array looks good.

Comment: First page looks good, but not the rest? Do you have sample HTML and PDF output? Have you looked at the [dompdf Unicode how-to](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/wiki/CPDFUnicode)?

Comment: Yes I looked into that and all my settings were right.. See my solution down here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved it:

First I took all the steps Phil Sturgeon suggested, except later on I found out I need to remove the META setting.

Before putting out the HTML to DomPDF, I did a PHP

```
$html = utf8_decode($html);
```

But before that you need to remove the META Charset from your HTML.
And be sure to add the proper page-ends in your document, I used a div with some CSS

```
<div style="page-break-before:always"></div>
```

on the end of each chapter.

Comment: Glad that worked, though it doesn't seem like the best solution. `utf8_decode()` will convert characters so that they're compatible with iso-8859-1, but characters where a close-enough match can't be found will be changed to a question mark.

Comment: Ah okay.. Strange though I got the question mark without doing the utf8_decode()... So despite of my settings for DomPDF it seems that the generated PDF is in iso-8859-1. Though I'm not very happy not having it in total control, glad I am that it works so my client can continue :)

Comment: It probably has something to do with character set conversion at some point in processing the document. By forcing your characters into iso-8859-1 you're avoiding some problems though the same issue could show up again in the future if non-supported characters are used.